# Is there something like @JsonIgnoreOtherProperties?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Jackson has the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation at field level which is awesome, but sometime it can be big.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "name", "phone", ... "20th item"})
private User user;
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
@JsonIgnoreOtherProperties("email")
private User user;
```

So this would ignore all fields but email.

Is there something like @JsonIgnoreOtherProperties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that exists but there are several ways of achieving what you want (other than your existing solution):

1) Using `@JsonView` (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews). See [What is the JSON View class in Jackson and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279782/what-is-the-json-view-class-in-jackson-and-how-does-it-work) for an example.

2) Creating a different `User` view which contains a minimal set of fields, perhaps `UserMinimal`. It might inherit from a common interface as your other `User` view to show they really represent the same entity.

3) Customizing the object mapper and using a filter. See [How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations) for an example.

Personally, I prefer the first solution if you have a simple use case and the second if you have a more complex one. I dislike the third option as I think customizing object mappers leads down an error prone path in my experience.

Your annotation idea sounds interesting though. I would consider putting it as a feature request (I think it would go https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues).