# Custom JSON serialization in Spring Framework and Apache CXF

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, dto

in my Spring Framework project I am writing web services (Apache CXF) where I am (de)serializing inputs and outputs using *JacksonJsonProvider*.

**I want to serialize DTO objects differently each time.** I know I can use custom serializer and override some of Jackson's functionality but my requirements that I want to do it differently every time!

**Example:**

here is my DTO class I want to serialize

```
public class MyDTO {

    private Long sessionId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    ...
}
```

here are my two webservice methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/example1")
public Response myWsMethodExample1(...) {
    MyDTO dto = new MyDto();
    ...
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(dto).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/example2")
public Response myWsMethodExample2(...) {
    MyDTO dto = new MyDto();
    ...
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(dto).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

I want that API call on **/example1 produces**:

```
{ "sessionId": 1, "fistName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "email": "john@smith.com" }
```

and call on **/example2 produces** the same DTO without, say, `email` and `sessionId`:

```
{ "fistName": "John", "lastName": "Smith" }
```

**How can I do this?**

How can I achieve this without actually having to use 2 different DTOs for a response? Is that even possible? Annotations like @JsonIgnoreProperty won't work because that would ignore a property permanently.

I am looking for the most elegant solution. Many thanks:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @JsonView to filter fields depending on the context of serialization. When returning data to a REST client, depending on which REST service was called, we need to limit which data will be serialized while using the same data model.

for more details can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279782/what-is-the-json-view-class-in-jackson-and-how-does-it-work) on stackoverflow

and also there is a good article about @JsonView and Spring security integration on [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-role-filter-json) to filter exposing data based on security

Comment: many thanks! This is what I was looking for. Although, is it okay to put annotations on DTO classes? The DTOs are in a separate module and now I have to include Jackson's dependency in the pom.xml there. What is the best practice? It solves the issue though.